# ASP.Net upgrade from 2.0 to 4.0+ gives JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'Validators' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

Here is the situation. Our internal website is being upgraded from ASP.Net 2.0 to 4.0 (I also have tried 4.5 and 4.6 in hopes it was fixed in those versions). We have a signature pad that is used for client signatures but it only works on IE11 or earlier versions since it uses an ActiveX control. So basically until we switch the Signature Pad we are stuck with IE 11.

Now when a control does a server side post back and it has a Validator control attached to it ( usually requiredfieldvalidator ) it will give the following error:

*JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'Validators' of undefined or null reference.*

This is the javascript method it gives the error (it fails on the line that I bolded):

```
function ValidatorOnChange(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    Page_InvalidControlToBeFocused = null;
    var targetedControl;
    if ((typeof(event.srcElement) != "undefined") && (event.srcElement != null)) {
        targetedControl = event.srcElement;
    }
    else {
        targetedControl = event.target;
    }
    var vals;
    if (typeof(targetedControl.Validators) != "undefined") { // here
        vals = targetedControl.Validators;
    }
    else {
        if (targetedControl.tagName.toLowerCase() == "label") {
            targetedControl = document.getElementById(targetedControl.htmlFor);
            vals = targetedControl.Validators;
        }
    }
    if (vals) {
        for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
            ValidatorValidate(vals[i], null, event);
        }
    }
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
}
```

I have looked all over the web for an answer with no luck. The error stops the page from going into the server side code. I can fix the issue by setting enableclientscript = false in the validator tag but I was hoping there was a better and quicker option.

Thanks.

Tim

Comment: I think your targetedControl has undefined as value. That's why when you are trying to access targetedControl.Validators, you get the error. Try to keep the debugger to check. Also include condition to ensure you get value for targetedControl

Comment: I understand that the targetedControl is undefined. I have debugged it but the problem is all of this code is inside the Validator control that comes with the ASP.Net framework. There is really no way to access it or change it that I am aware of. It worked fine with IE10 or 11 before I upgraded from ASP.Net 2.0. I was hoping there was a SP or Hotfix to address the issue.

Comment: fwiw: have you tried using `if(Page.IsValid)...` in the code behind? maybe it'll help trace something...maybe not in the js though. another randomness: see if anything shows up in trace `your-url.aspx/trace.axd` (needs to be on in web.config).

Comment: Here is an update. Yes I ended up checking the validation on the server side too since the client side validator was giving me javascript errors. I ended up setting enableclientscript to false because otherwise you got the js errors and they were preventing the server side code to run. Certain server controls (DropDown and Checkboxes) using a validator caused the errors but certain ones did not (RadioButtons).